# How do I create a dd IMAGE from LVM for recovery purposes

Tags: dd, disk, lvm

How do I backup a LVM partition to an image for recovery purposes?

I am trying to run dd on /dev/sda2, but it crashes after ca 8 hours, at around 380G

```
 sudo lvmdiskscan
  /dev/centos/swap [       3.89 GiB] 
  /dev/sda1        [     500.00 MiB] 
  /dev/centos/root [      50.00 GiB] 
  /dev/sda2        [     465.27 GiB] LVM physical volume
  /dev/centos/home [     411.38 GiB] 
  /dev/sdb1        [     931.51 GiB] 
  3 disks
  2 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  1 LVM physical volume
```

Anyway, could running from a stick make any difference?

Comment: Backing up a physical volume doesn't make much sense. Consider backing up the logical volume.

Comment: if=/dev/centos/home ?

Comment: What command are you using? (Copy-paste!) What do you mean by “it crashes”? (Again: copy-paste any error message.) What are you backing up: the whole volume group, or one logical volume?

Comment: image backups don't make much sense.  backup the files in the volume (e.g. with `tar`, `cp`, `rsync`, etc) rather than image backups of the VG or LV.

Comment: I want to recover deleted files.

Comment: @Gilles, I am putting putting more info into:

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291423/dd-crashing-what-to-do-about-it

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was previously answered on Serverfault.

https://serverfault.com/questions/219234/lvm-dd-lvm

> First of all you should create an LVM that is at least the same size of the original one. Then you can do something like:
>
> `local# dd if=/dev/vglocal/lvm-old | ssh remote dd of=/dev/vgremote/lvm-new`
>
> And that should do it. If you already have a file with the original lvm on the remote server, then something very similar can be done:
>
> `remote# dd if=/path/to/img of=/dev/vgremote/lvm-new`
>
> You could also add the option bs to increment the blocksize used by dd, to speed up the process:
>
> `# dd if=... of=... bs=131072`

Comment: It doesn't help that much as I am already using the dd-command, I don't have the same layout, and probably an image-file is best