# dd crashing - what to do about it

Tags: dd, disk-image

I have `dd` crashing after running a few hours. 
Typically with a message like

```
Input/output error
68424+1 records in
68424+1 records out
342124883968 bytes (342 GB) copied, 5114.68 s, 66.9 MB/s
```

Is there something I can do about it?  Is there some way I can use the output?
Or restart where it left off?

Is there any reason to think it is because the partition being backed up is being used?

It always crashes around 70-80%, often when the partition should be less-used.

Since this process takes so long, it is difficult to try different things.

I output to an image.  I could probably use a partition, but LVM is involved:

```
sudo lvmdiskscan
/dev/centos/swap [       3.89 GiB] 
/dev/sda1        [     500.00 MiB] 
/dev/centos/root [      50.00 GiB] 
/dev/sda2        [     465.27 GiB] LVM physical volume
/dev/centos/home [     411.38 GiB] 
/dev/sdb1        [     931.51 GiB] 
3 disks
2 partitions
0 LVM physical volume whole disks
1 LVM physical volume


dd conv=sync,noerror if=/dev/centos/home bs=2000000   of=/run/media/ob/X_1T_Media1GHD-PCTU3/c/sd9e22_cel.image
dd: error reading '/dev/centos/home': Input/output error
171062+1 records in
171063+0 records out
342126000000 bytes (342 GB) copied, 4625.3 s, 74.0 MB/s
220856+2 records in
220858+0 records out
441716000000 bytes (442 GB) copied, 6138.1 s, 72.0 MB/s
```

Friday Morning

`ddrescue --sector-size=2048 --cluster-size=$((256*512)) --sparse --verbose /dev/centos/home /run/media/ob/X_1T_Media1GHD-PCTU3/c/sd7c_dd.image /run/media/ob/X_1T_Media1GHD-PCTU3/c/sd7c_dd.map`

GNU ddrescue 1.18.1
About to copy 441714 MBytes from /dev/centos/home to /run/media/ob/X_1T_Media1GHD-PCTU3/c/sd7c_dd.image
    Starting positions: infile = 0 B,  outfile = 0 B
    Copy block size: 131072 sectors       Initial skip size: 32 sectors
Sector size: 2048 Bytes

Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
rescued:   441714 MB,  errsize:    8192 B,  current rate:        0 B/s
   ipos:   342124 MB,   errors:       1,    average rate:   60675 kB/s
   opos:   342124 MB, run time:    2.02 h,  successful read:       9 s ago
Finished

But

 `extundelete sd7c_dd.image  --restore-directory /home/ob/p -o /tmp/tt
extundelete: Bad magic number in super-block when trying to open filesystem sd7c_dd.image`

```
/dev/mapper/centos-home on /home type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

Comment: Can i somehow use the seek-option

Comment: Can you show us the full error message, in particular did it say "reading" or "writing"?

Comment: Please provide the full command you're running. It's not possible to divine the source and destination without that.

Comment: I have put the latest run at the end of the question because of the formatting.

Comment: Put some more info

Comment: You can't use extundelete on an XFS filesystem. That command is for extN filesystems.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there some way to know if it is valid?

Comment: What, the image? `fsck -t xfs -n /.../imagefile`

Answer (score 6):

You should never run `dd` on a mounted file system, because that can corrupt the image, esp. if you want to do a backup. You may want to use `tar` instead.

If you are sure that the device is *not* failing, you may use the `seek` (for seeking N blocks into the output file) and `skip=N` (for skipping N blocks of the input) flags. On a Linux system, you can use the `dmesg` command to get the current kernel log.

If you are unsure whether the device you want to copy from may be failing, I would recommend using `ddrescue` to get an image of the device. That tool does not abort on read errors and logs the positions of blocks it failed to read properly.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to image copy a partition that's in use you are setting yourself up for a really bad fall. Copying a partition like this requires that nothing is writing to it. At all.

If you can quiesce the partition you could use `ddrescue`, which is designed to read disks and partitions with faulty sectors. A typical invocation to extract `/dev/sda1` to the image file `/media/sda1.img` would be like this:

```
ddrescue --sector-size=2048 --cluster-size=$((64*512)) --sparse --verbose /dev/sda1 /media/sda1.img /media/sda1.map
```

The sector and cluster sizes set `ddrescue` up for reading 64MB units. You might want to try increasing this to 128MB or even 256MB, but be aware this won't necessarily increase throughput.

In your particular case your source partition is actually an LVM volume, so this is a great help: you can take a snapshot of the partition to backup. In this example I've called it `home-snap`.

```
lvcreate --snapshot --name home-snap --size 1G /dev/centos/home
ddrescue --sector-size=2048 --cluster-size=$((64*512)) --sparse --verbose /dev/centos/home-snap /run/media/ob/X_1T_Media1GHD-PCTU3/c/sd9e22_cel.image /run/media/ob/X_1T_Media1GHD-PCTU3/c/sd9e22_cel.map
lvremove -y /dev/centos/home-snap
```

Comment: I think I need "faster" options, also that I am sure it continues on error.  Default dd does 1G/min, increasing buff-size is faster.  Also, what is the size of the output?

Comment: There is a finite speed at which you can read your partition and write the image. It's not possible to go faster than that. The size of the output is the size of the input; just like `dd`.

Comment: It seems much slower that dd with default values.  dd with changing buffsize is much faster.

Comment: I have added the LVM-information to the question.

Comment: seems I do not have enough extents for the lvcreate.

Comment: @Olav, can you unmount `/dev/centos/home` for the purposes of backing it up? If so, then do so and apply `ddrescue` to it directly. Otherwise you're going to need to snapshot the device. The snapshot must be large enough to handle any changes thrown at the filesystem while it's being copied. I chose 1GB but you might get away with 10M if it's almost entirely idle. If you have no extents left - and cannot obtain any - then you _cannot safely copy the partition_ unless you unmount it..

Comment: I can use a Linux USB, but if I know I can start it an finish in a few hours:-)

Could I do the first step and move back?
(Added some info)

Comment: @Olva, did you copy the filesystem with it unmounted or snapshotted? If not, any unprotected block-level copy _will_ be corrupt (`dd` or `ddrescue`). What type of filesystem is `/dev/centos/home`?

Comment: /dev/mapper/centos-home on /home type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)  - if you think the bad magic is because it was mounted I will do it with a live usb.

Answer (score 2):

If the device is larger than the 342GB it copied, you most likely have a bad sector on this disk.

You can use `seek` and `skip` with identical values to resume.

```
dd <your previous options here ...> seek=68424 skip=68424 conv=notrunc
```

`68424` will most likely just produce the same I/O error again, so you'll have to increase it. You didn't say which block size you used (and I'm too lazy to do the math), for skipping smaller error regions you might prefer a smaller blocksize (then you have to adapt `seek` and `skip` accordingly).

Don't use `conv=noerror`, [it corrupts things](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/195171). If you encounter more errors, use `ddrescue`, it's a tool that handles read errors better than `dd` does.

Comment: What happens if seek/skip are not accurate?  How would this look with my last ouput?

Comment: `seek` and `skip` must be identical, otherwise the result will be corrupt. If the value is too small, you're re-copying already copied data. If it's too large, you're leaving a hole (which you could fill later if you knew where it was - you're better off with `ddrescue` at this point).