# How can I check if a dd disk image is consistent (i.e. not corrupt)

Tags: dd

I have a `dd` disk image.  How can I check if it is consistent?  (It doesn't have to be an exact copy.)

I am trying to run `extundelete`, but I don't know if it's failing because the underlying filesystem is `xfs`, or because the image is corrupt.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the contents of the disk, `fsck` is probably your best bet.

Comment: `extundelete` is *not* useful for *xfs* filesystems, i think.

Comment: I already answered this on [your earlier question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/291423/100397). You cannot use `extundelete` on an XFS filesystem. You can verify if the filesystem image is plausible by running `fsck`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `fsck.xfs` on the partition image would be a good way to know if the file is corrupted or not.

Since it is a disk image rather than a partition image, you'll need to extract the partition from the disk.

You can get its size and position from

```
sfdisk -l -uS diskImageFile
```

and then extract it with

```
dd if=diskImageFile of=partitionFile bs=blockSize skip=partitionOffset count=partitionSize
```

Comment: `kpartx` is a nice tool, it can work on a image file and list partitions, mount them and so on ... for example: `kpartx -av diskImageFile`

Comment: How do I know id the issue is dd, xfs or LVM?

Comment: @Olav:  Did you run `fsck.xfs` on the extracted partition yet?

Comment: fsck gave a bisarre  output

Comment: @Olav:  Why do you say it gave a bizarre output without giving the actual output?

Comment: If you wish to check the consistency of an XFS filesystem or
repair a damaged filesystem, see xfs_repair(8).

Comment: In the end I found I could unmount it, and boot into root on the host.  I used the disks GUI app to create an image.  It was quite good with trying to copy as much as possible.